# can we pattern match in a case with a fct?

Tags: haskell

I was wondering If I could use a method instead of a constant in a case, passing from this :

```
fromEvent :: Event -> Maybe WorkspaceCreated
fromEvent event =
  case (eventName $ header event) of
    "workspaceCreated" -> Just WorkspaceCreated {eventId = CoreEvent.eventId $ header event, workspaceId = aggregateId $ header event}
    _ -> Nothing
```

to something like this :

```
eventNameForWorkspaceCreated = "workspaceCreated" :: String
fromEvent :: Event -> Maybe WorkspaceCreated
fromEvent event =
  case (eventName $ header event) of
    eventNameForWorkspaceCreated -> Just WorkspaceCreated {eventId = CoreEvent.eventId $ header event, workspaceId = aggregateId $ header event}
    _ -> Nothing
```

In the last example it takes eventNameForWorkspaceCreated for the name of a variable which make sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly. Names are treated as irrefutable patterns; the value of the name is not used as the pattern to match.

Instead, you can define a pattern synonym using the `PatternSynonyms` extension.

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms -#}
pattern EventNameForWorkspaceCreated = "workspaceCreated"

fromEvent :: Event -> Maybe WorkspaceCreated
fromEvent event = case (eventName $ header event) of
                EventNameForWorkspaceCreated -> Just WorkspaceCreated {eventId = CoreEvent.event}
                _ -> Nothing
```

However, guard syntax is probably simpler if you don't really need pattern matching. (`String` values can be compared for equality.)

```
fromEvent event | eventName $ header event == eventNameForWorkspaceCreated = Just WorkspaceCreated {eventId = CoreEvent.event}
                | otherwise = Nothing
```

Comment: Don't pattern synonyms need to start with a capital letter?

Comment: yeah I knew the way using guard, but you made me discover this PatternSynonyms ! thanks :-)